# java sql exception occures repeatedly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1064

```
public void Deposite() throws Exception

    {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank";

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.print("Enter your A/c no. : " );
                acNo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                String sql = "SELECT Name,Ac_No,Balance FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Ac_No=?";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(2,acNo);

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    String name = rs.getString("Name");
                    int acNo = rs.getInt("Ac_No");
                    float bal = rs.getFloat("Balance");

                    System.out.println("    "+name+"        "+acNo+"        "+bal);
                }
```

i am getting this exception....plz help me...

error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one Parameter to bind. Which has the index one:

So:

```
ps.setInt(2,acNo);
```

must be:

```
ps.setInt(1,acNo);
```

Comment: Bt i have provided acNo at 2nd index on the given table... @jens

Comment: Is this problem related to the index numbering 9 or parameter ????

Comment: setInt first parameter relates to the index of "?" expressions in your query. You only have one, so the setInt should bind to "1" only.